# Insert array into postgres array

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert an array into a postrges table as an array.  I'm receiving the following error:

```
jobsArray = ['Vice President', 'Technical Services Consultant']

db.execute("""INSERT INTO test VALUES (%s)""", (jobsArray,))
```

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

I've tried many different solutions recommended on stackoverflow but with no success, errors vary but this is the most common error.  I tried converting to a tuple but same behavior.

Comment: Try: `db.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES ({})".format(', '.join(['%s' for items in t])), t)` If you have a list. Can't test and feel it might fail for single values.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure why the error should be regarding string formatting, the usual error is not providing enough "binding parameters"

Comment: `db.execute(sqlalchemy.sql.text("""INSERT INTO test VALUES (:x)"""), {'x': jobsArray})`

Answer (score 0):

I think Postgres array syntax uses curly brackets. Source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html

If you are using SQLAlchemy, it can perform the conversion automatically, but I believe you will need to create a data model for your table.